# Typed variable declaration : Class: EventRequestDTO not found in namespace

Tags: java, jmeter

I am using jmeter for the first time . I have added a beanShell sampler , I get this eroor
Typed variable declaration : ***Class: EventRequestDTO not found in namespace***
Who know why?
and Here is my code :
**

```
import event.Events;
import dto.EventRequestDTO;
System.out.println("Hi");
String[] t = {};
EventRequestDTO eDto = new EventRequestDTO("This", "This", "here", "condition_01","100", "It occurred", " return true;", "0", "0", "0", t, false);
```

**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jmeter needs fat jar. So I added a plugin and then I ran package on maven and it solved the problem

```
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>

        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>

    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you forgot to copy the .jar file containing your `EventRequestDTO` class to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and/or restart JMeter to pick it (them) up.

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating.

See [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) article for more information.

Comment: I have added jar of project to JMter , (both paths : lib/exec and lib ) but it doesnt work